# Distributing Python application as a debian package, but as service

Tags: python, linux, debian, setuptools

Hello I'm trying to create a debian package for my application, well this is th structure:

```
Project
  |start.py
  |ProyectPackage2/...
  |ProyectPackage1/...
  |DataExtra/...
  |Settings/service.cfg
```

When I want to run my app I write:

> python start.py

and it works.

but I want to distribute my app in a debian package and I want the following:

1- After installing debian package I want have a new command into /usr/sbin/ like my_service

2- Extra Content must located into /usr/lib/my_service/extracontent

3- Service must run when package were installed

I have tried

> python stdeb

and it create a debian structure for packaging but, i'd like add script to do: create command, copy content, service install.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your `debian/` folder, you need the following files to solve your problem:

**init** with your init script.  This file will be installed to `/etc/init.d/myservice` and will be started automatically at boot.  You can (and should) use `/etc/init.d/skeleton` as a template for your init script.

**install** with a list of files to be installed, along with target directories.  For example

```
DataExtra/* usr/lib/my_service/extracontent
```

might fit your project.  Check the manual page of `dh_install`.

Other files that you need are `debian/rules`, `debian/control` and `debian/changelog` (you need to change `control` and `changelog` according to your project).

Check the *Debian New Maintainers' Guide* for more detailed instructions.